# Meteor: UI Easing for collection items between reactive changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, responsive-design

I have a thumbnail collection in meteor used in a template as below:

```
<template name="templThumbnails">
    {{#each thumbnails}}
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{this.Path}}" alt="" />
        </a>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Whenever the `thumbnails` collection changes, this template gets updated.

> My question is: How do I transit the changes smoothly in UI (between
>   old items and new items) ?

Not much of web ui expert - hence seeking help from pros. When the `thumbnails` change, it may have added new items, removed few old items etc. (Something on the lines of isotope and quicksand js, but works with meteor collections and has responsive capabilities)

Answer (score 1):

This is going to involve `_uihooks`, which is a very poorly documented feature of Meteor (at present).  However, there's a good tutorial [here](http://www.webtempest.com/meteorjs-animation) that's just been released, and there are a [couple](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/momentum) of [packages](https://atmospherejs.com/frozeman/animation-helper) which try to abstract away the required logic and make things easier for you, although there are trade-offs in terms of what you can do with both.